# Problems converting CRC16 function from C to JAVA without unsigned int

Tags: java, c, crc16

I have to create a CRC16 checksum for a firmware update. When I send this Data (converted from hex-string to byte[])

> 020000810000120000000002F001128100000C9462050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C94

I get following CRC16 from the controller

> -17514

now I try to check this in Java, but I can't get the same value.

This are the original functions in C:

```
static uint16_t crc16_update(uint16_t crc, uint8_t a)
{
  crc ^= a;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    if (crc & 1)
      crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001;
    else
      crc = (crc >> 1);
  }
  return crc;
}


static uint16_t crc16(const uint8_t *b, size_t l)
{
  uint16_t crc = 0;
  while (l-- > 0)
    crc = crc16_update(crc, *b++);
  return crc;
}
```

this are my converted functions in java:

```
public static int crc16_update(int crc, int a) {
    crc ^= a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if ((crc & 1) != 0) {
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001;
        } else {
            crc = (crc << 1);
        }
    }
    return crc;
}

public static int crc16(byte[] bytes) {
    int crc = 0;
    for (byte b:bytes) {
        crc = crc16_update(crc, b);
    }
    return crc;
}
```

... but it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Look into your seventh line. Original: ´(crc >> 1)´ Your code: ´(crc << 1)´. I don't know, whether it fixes the issue, but however...

Comment: Isn't it at least a little unusual that you get a negative number `-17514` from a routine that calculates an unsigned result? By any chance, does your Java routine return `48022` instead?

Comment: no, now i get 14646 in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the right way. Now it work's! I think the problem was the intern converting between short and int.

```
public static int crc16_update(int crc, byte a) {
    crc ^= ((a+128) & 0xff);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if ((crc & 1) != 0) {
            crc = ((crc >>> 1) ^ 0xA001) & 0xffff;
        }
        else {
            crc = (crc >>> 1) & 0xffff;
        }
    }
    return crc;
}

public static short crc16(byte[] bytes) {
    int crc = 0;
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        crc = crc16_update(crc, b);
    }
    return (short) crc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int crc16_update(int crc, int a) {
    crc ^= a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if ((crc & 1) != 0) {
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001;
        } else {
            crc = (crc << 1);
```

As [mentioned by looper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529510/problems-converting-crc16-function-from-c-to-java-without-unsigned-int#comment18523930_13529510), you have a `>> 1` there in the C code.

```
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Now for the other function:

```
public static int crc16(byte[] bytes) {
    int crc = 0;
    for (byte b:bytes) {
        crc = crc16_update(crc, b);
```

`crc16_update` takes an `int` as second argument in Java, a `uint8_t` in C. When the byte `b` has its most significant/sign bit set, the value is negative, and thus when converted to `int` as argument to `crc16_update`, sign-extended, thus you get a lot of 1-bits that you don't have in C.

You need to mask out all bits but the least significant 8,

```
crc16_update(crc, ((int)b) & 0xFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `>>>` operator.

In Java, this is the *unsigned* shift operator, as opposed to `>>` which preserves the sign.

Also note that `uint16_t` is a 16 bit type, as is `short` in Java. Try to use the appropriate bit length, when rewriting algorithms that work on a bit level.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not that integers a signed in java but you use the wrong datatype. `int` has 32 bit and the algorithm you use is sensitive to the datasize of the types. Use `short` for 16 bit and `byte` for 8 bit.

Also use `>>>`, where necessary, as mentioned by @Anony-Mousse.

Comment: i've changed it, but it doesn't work. no i get 14646 from 020000810000120000000002F001128100000C9462050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C9481050C94